# Inability to start weblogic BEA-002606

Tags: weblogic

I run a managed instance of Weblogic 10.3 on my mac box. One day i tried starting it and i got this error message

```
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file /Users/xx/bfdev/bea10/user_projects/domains/xx/servers/admin/logs/xx.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to /Users/xx/bfdev/bea10/user_projects/domains/xx/servers/admin/logs/xx.log00101. Log messages will continue to be logged in /Users/xx/bfdev/bea10/user_projects/domains/xx/servers/admin/logs/benefitfocusDomain.log.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "Default[3]". The address fe80:0:0:0:2acf:e9ff:fe64:20eb%0 might be incorrect or another process is using port 7001: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address.> 
*<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "Default[2]". The address fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 might be incorrect or another process is using port 7001: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
**<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "localhost", maps to multiple IP addresses: 127.0.0.1, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 192.168.2.93:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 192.168.1.2:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>** 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "admin" for domain "xx" running in Development Mode>* 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
<Jun 2, 2013 5:19:34 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Since i am a new mac user, assigning and reassigning port numbers is an area i have little knowledge. Any help would be appreciated on this issue.
PS: NO vague answers. Specific responses on which steps to take would be of help here as i have tried google-ing and it has been hell.

Answer (score 5):

I would manually edit the config.xml file that lives in your:

```
<domain home>/config directory.
```

Find your

```
<server>
```

and edit the

```
<listen-address>
```

to use the exact IP of your machine. You can also change

```
<listen-port>
```

in there to something other than the default. Try something like 65501 to see if you can bring it up. And yes, weblogic is hell.

Comment: Resolved. I used the admin console to manually enter the listen port. Which in my case was 127. *. *. *

Answer (score 0):

When you change the IP address
Change the IP Address in 
/**etc/hosts** - IP address was changed [Linux]