# Independent Manage servers in weblogic

Tags: weblogic

I have two servers Server A and Server B :
I want to make admin server on Server A and manage servers on server B .Manage servers on B will be pointing to Server A admin . I tried using this configuration but manage servers are not able to start giving below error, Admin server A is running

**Configuration : 
Server A : Only Admin , Port 9001
Server B : No admin , Only 2 Manage servers : Port 7002, 7003 pointing to Server A admin**

**Error logs :

```
<May 7, 2014 4:11:40 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with IBM J9 VM Version 2.3 from IBM Corporation>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:41 PM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 9.2 MP3  Mon Mar 10 08:28:41 EDT 2008 1096261 >
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Emergency> <Management> <BEA-141151> <The admin server could not be reached at http://172.21.153.108.>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Info> <Configuration Management> <BEA-150018> <This server is being started in managed server independence mode in the absence of the admin server.>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000215> <Loaded License : /usr/local/bea/bea92/license.bea>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:44 PM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /usr/local/bea/bea92/user_projects/domains/RxConnect/servers/Store_MS1/logs/Store_MS1.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Error> <Security> <BEA-090870> <The realm "myrealm" failed to be loaded: weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1.
weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:822)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:851)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1007)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:854)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:342)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:292)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:263)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:71)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:461)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:136)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
        at netscape.ldap.LDAPConnSetupMgr.connectServer(LDAPConnSetupMgr.java:499)
        at netscape.ldap.LDAPConnSetupMgr.openSerial(LDAPConnSetupMgr.java:435)
        at netscape.ldap.LDAPConnSetupMgr.connect(LDAPConnSetupMgr.java:274)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:
There are 1 nested errors:
weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:090399]Security Services Unavailable
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:898)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1029)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:854)
        at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down>
<May 7, 2014 4:11:48 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>**
```

Comment: The problem is:
`The admin server could not be reached at http://172.21.153.108.`
Can you add on how did you start the managed server?

Comment: Verify the listen-address and port look good as mentioned in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887459/inability-to-start-weblogic-bea-002606/16900523#16900523

Comment: Admin server 0n 108 (Server A )is uptime and running. On server B Started manager server like this : sh startManagedWebLogic.sh Store_MS1 http://172.21.153.108:9001  .

Comment: Could you help me on below confusion : If I make manage server on server B and start this manage server with Admin on server A. then whose resources will be used for this manage server ? JVM of server A or server B will be used ?

Comment: If you create managed server B, EVERYTHING related to that server runs on B. The JVM will be running on B. So if you manually run `startManagedWeblogic.sh <server_name>` you need to run that on B. If you want to start B from the Admin console, you need to set up a nodemanager on B. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/nodemgr.html#1150128

Comment: Thanks.. Can I run my manage server on server B using Admin on server A without setting cluster.