# Weblogic 12c web application not start properly after server reboot

Tags: oracle, deployment, intellij-idea, ejb, weblogic12c

I have a EJB project build from IntelliJ 14, there are a lots of EJBs (include session Beans and JPA entity Beans) in the ear. This project is business services layer in my project.

My development and staging environments are both as Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.3), JDK version is 1.8.0.x.

I deployed it in my development environment (WebLogic 12c -12.1.3, downloaded and installed at end of 2015) by using install it on administration console which is working fine, every time I reboot my development machine, it will start deploy it properly and provide services to EJB clients.  But when I tried to deploy it in my staging environment (WebLogic 12c -12.1.3, downloaded and installed last week).

I found there is some different between two packages, early 12c was installed folder ~/mywls/wls12130 but the newly downloaded installed in ~/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home. I believe there must have some different, but oracle name it as same version. I don't know why?

The two WebLogics have some different behaviour too, early version works IPv4 address on 7001 port, newer version works in IPv6 address on 7001.

Use same .ear package to deploy it in two machine, early WebLogic shows it works fine after a little and newer version too.

After reboot servers, early version can restart it self, every thing works well, but the newer version some time administration console waiting on 7001 on localhost and nowhere, if I run lsof I got such result:

```
macmini16g:~ cidylong$ sudo lsof -nP | grep TCP |grep 7001
java      284        xxxx  354u     IPv6 0x43c511fce2ab4ac3       0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:7001 (LISTEN)
java      284        xxxx  355u     IPv6 0x43c511fce5646bc3       0t0     TCP [::1]:7001 (LISTEN)
```

In this situation, we can't connect to administration console from LAN as it only waiting for localhost.

If you restart server again, and run lost again, you may get different result, you probably see three rows as:

```
macmini16g:~ cidylong$ sudo lsof -nP | grep TCP |grep 7001
java      277        xxxx  354u     IPv6 0x20915e23819739       0t0     TCP [::1]:7001 (LISTEN)
java      277        xxxx  355u     IPv6 0x20915e263bd239       0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:7001 (LISTEN)
java      277        xxxx  356u     IPv6 0x20915e263bcd39       0t0     TCP [fe80:4::ca2a:14ff:fe58:cd42]:7001 (LISTEN)
```

This time you can connect through IPv6 in LAN, it is very funny.
There is an other issue with newer version, the same web application .ear not start properly after server reboot.

After we login to administration console, click in my domain -> deployments -> shows a table in the content section with all deployed applications. But the application State column shows Admin instead of Active, no thing shows in Health column instead of a green tick symbol and OK. Which means. If click in Admin linkage in State column, you was brought over to other page shows the detailed status, in last column (Target-Specific State), shows information as: "AdminServer=Failed".

If you tick the application in the list and click start button from the dropdown select, for example, servicing all requests selected, then the application will start and the State shows Active and Health column shows green tick and Ok.

Such means, every time server reboot, the application has to be manually started. Quite annoy!!

Any idea and advice are welcome.

**Edit:**

I configured  in my domain/config/config.xml. but seems not works. nothing different.

```
<listen-address></listen-address>
```

I leave it empty or I put

```
<listen-address>10.0.1.1/24</listen-address>
```

no different.

Comment: What is the `listen-address` set to in the admin console for your server? Try changing it from localhost to the actual fully qualified host name or the IP address. Or try something like I recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887459/inability-to-start-weblogic-bea-002606/16900523#16900523

Comment: I configured <listen-address> in my domain/config/config.xm. but seems not works. nothing changed.

Comment: Why did you use 10.0.1.1 instead os 127.0.1.1?
Is it a misstype? or it may be the problem...